# "misaligned register" showing while syetem is on suspend mode

Tags: 12.04, nouveau

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.When I click on the `suspend` button it suspends but the following text is coming here

```
[3265.605475][drm]nouveau 0000:00:0d.0:======= misaligned reg 0x00600810=======
[3265.605475][drm]nouveau 0000:00:0d.0:======= misaligned reg 0x00600810=======
```

Though apparently it is not bothering my system, I am just interested to know why the text is coming?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47182 these miss aligned accesses should be generally harmless, so do not worry.

Here is more technical info about what is aligned / miss aligned access: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/

To make things even more complicated some nvidia graphic cards (for example C51) uses non aligned addresses (most probably as a software workaround to some hardware issue).

Nouveau driver reads constants/script from video bios to perform suspend and resume and most probably some of these tells it to perform non aligned access, which is skipped.

You do not specify which model you have, but I would tend to believe, that either bios script has a bug or it is a workaround for some hardware issue and current suspend implementation of nouveau drivers is not as efficient as it could possibly be.

Anyway upgrading your video bios may solve the problem.